# Sculpt brush set not working correctly

Tags: sculpting

I downloaded the Orb brush set from blend swap and the instructions are useless in my case.

Blender cant find the textures or the icons for when you want to choose a brush. I can manually select the texture from the folder but the icon for it is still not visible.

I guess what I need to know is where do I put the "textures/icons" folders to make the icons visible and blender be able to find them with out me looking for them manually.

Comment: I could see how that might be helpful for an addon but its just a brush pack. The entire download is a blend file, and 2 folders of images. https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/86419 The pack I'm referring to. Not entirely sure how i would treat this like an addon? Sorry for not understanding!

Comment: Fixed it! I was dumb and was appending from a separate .blend. Not the one that is supposed to go in the "config" of blender. Once i appended from the correct place it fixed the problem. Also, I'm new here, is there a way to mark this as solved or do i just leave it?

Answer (score 1):

Once you put the .blend, textures, and icons folders in c:>users>YourName>AppData>Roaming>BlenderFoundation>Blender>2.79>config, open a new .blend and append the brushes from the .blend in the location above and nowhere else. Save as a new start up file and you're good to go!